# How to increase the vertical split window size in Vim

Tags: vim, window, viewport

`:vsplit` (short form: `:vs`) split the Vim viewport vertically. `:30vs` splits the viewport, making the new window 30 characters wide. Once this 30 char window is created, how would one change it's size to 31 or 29?

With horizontal windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> increases the number of lines by one. What is the equivalent command to increase the columns by one?

Comment: You can also do Ctrl-W 5+ to increase window height by 5 (or any number).  Same goes for Ctrl-W 5-

Comment: `:h ^w` to see list of window commands. `:h ^ww` to see help of normal command `Ctrl-w w`.

Answer (score 504, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>

and

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd><</kbd>

to make the window wider or narrower.

Comment: or `:30winc > ` and `:30winc <` to have 30 more/less characters wide.

Comment: or `30CTRL-W >` to stay in the spirit of the answer.

Comment: `:vertical resize 30` to resize the current window to exactly 30 characters wide.

Comment: `:res <N>` to set the current window size to exactly N rows (for height not width)

Comment: So stupid, so intuitive, and still I didn't thought of '<', '>'. Thank you! And is there any key similar to Ctrl-W, = for vertical splits?

Comment: or `CTRL-W =` to make them equal

Answer (score 279):

And <kbd>Ctr</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>

will make them equal

Comment: `:winc =` This will also make them equal.

Comment: That's for horizontal splits, right? What would be the equivalent for vertical splits?

Comment: @JoséRamón This command works for both horizontal and vertical splits.

Answer (score 118):

In case you need **HORIZONTAL SPLIT** resize as well:
The command is the same for *all* splits, just the *parameter* changes:

`-` `+` instead of `<` `>`

*Examples*:
**Decrease** horizontal size by 10 columns

```
:10winc -
```

**Increase** horizontal size by 30 columns

```
:30winc +
```

or within normal mode:

*Horizontal splits*

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd>

*Vertical splits*

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd><</kbd> (decrease)

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd> (increase)

Comment: +1. Just a minor comment: according to `:he winc` `ctrl+w [count] {arg}` works as well...

Comment: What is the `10winc +/-` equivalent for vertical? I have `vertical resize 30`, but the shorter commands are preferred imo

Answer (score 54):

Another tip from my side:

In order to set the window's width to let's say exactly 80 columns, use

```
80 CTRL+W |
```

In order to set it to maximum width, just omit the preceding number:

```
CTRL+W |
```

Comment: HEIGHT: This parameters' counterpart is "_" (shift+-) for adjusting the height. It's actually very easy to remember visually, since | is literally the vertical split and _ is literally the horizontal split line. Example: 15 CTRL+W _ Sets the current splits height to 15 rows. Another way to remember: you need SHIFT for absolute sizes, since both | and _ require shift to be pressed

Answer (score 34):

I have these mapped in my .gvimrc to let me hit command-[arrow] to move the height and width of my current window around:

```
" resize current buffer by +/- 5 
nnoremap <D-left> :vertical resize -5<cr>
nnoremap <D-down> :resize +5<cr>
nnoremap <D-up> :resize -5<cr>
nnoremap <D-right> :vertical resize +5<cr>
```

For MacVim, you have to put them in your .gvimrc (and not your .vimrc) as they'll otherwise get overwritten by the system .gvimrc

Comment: what does that <cr> mean in the end? Haven't saw that in nnoremap before

Comment: it's short for "carriage return", basically it's the equivalent of the user hitting return

Comment: and is `<D-left>` = CTRL-D and left arrow?

Answer (score 14):

Along the same lines, I use the following in my `.vimrc` to let me move through the splits, automatically expanding the one I'm moving to to its full size and shrinking all the rest to their minimum height or width:

```
" Switch between window splits using big J or K and expand the split to its 
" full size. 
" 
" Move vertically in the window through the horizontal splits... 
map <C-J> <C-w>j<C-w>_ 
map <C-K> <C-w>k<C-w>_ 

" Move horizontally in the window through the vertical splits... 
map <C-H> <C-w>h<C-w>\| 
map <C-L> <C-w>l<C-w>\|
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what I am using as of now:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>= :exe "resize " . (winheight(0) * 3/2)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>- :exe "resize " . (winheight(0) * 2/3)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>0 :exe "vertical resize " . (winwidth(0) * 3/2)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>9 :exe "vertical resize " . (winwidth(0) * 2/3)<CR>
```

Answer (score 8):

For changing width use "vertical resize" and for changing height use "resize".

I have done following mapping in my .vimrc

1. <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> will increase width of the selected split
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> will decrease width of the selected split
3. <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> will increase height of the selected split
4. <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> will decrease height of the selected split

My .vimrc code:

```
nmap <M-Right> :vertical resize +1<CR>
nmap <M-Left> :vertical resize -1<CR>
nmap <M-Down> :resize +1<CR>
nmap <M-Up> :resize -1<CR>
```

[Vim Resize Splits more quickly](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Resize_splits_more_quickly)

Answer (score 6):

I am using numbers to resize by mapping the following in .vimrc

```
nmap 7 :res +2<CR> " increase pane by 2 
nmap 8 :res -2<CR> " decrease pane by 2
nmap 9 :vertical res +2<CR> " vertical increase pane by 2
nmap 0 :vertical res -2<CR> " vertical decrease pane by 2
```

Comment: I think you mean `nmap 9 :vertical res +2<CR>` instead of `-2` for `vertical increase`

Comment: This is really a nice binding. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am using the below commands for this:

```
set lines=50     " For increasing the height to 50 lines (vertical)
set columns=200  " For increasing the width to 200 columns (horizontal)
```